# Which stem would breathing go in?

Tags: stems, mix

Just curious which stem would breathing end up in?  Its a chase scene that I had to adr entirely and so I have looped in breathing.  I have it on a separate channel for mixing purposes but does the breathing end up in the dx stem? or would it maybe go into an fx stem.

Answer (score 6):

Back when i used to QC feature mixes, M+Es would often be accompanied by an "options track": a mono track with nothing but the breaths and non verbal vocalisations. This makes the most sense to me, as it gives the dubbing house the option of using it or not, while keeping vocal stuff out of the M+E.

To achieve this, i'm guessing it'd be best to keep your breaths in the dial stem, but on separate "Breath Tracks" so you can also send them to an options track (rather than the M+E).

The small effort this takes can save so much time in dubbing!

Comment: Thanks, I am going to be mixing this one, but the question just kind of came up for future reference once I work on something that I am not the only sound person.

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure if i was totally clear, but i meant when dubbing into other languages for foreign distribution. If you're not delivering an M+E, then breaths should just go into the dial stem, easy.

Answer (score 3):

Dialogue stem if it was recorded in ADR by the original actor.

The Dialogue Editor can leave it in the M&E mix as they have to prepare the production sound effects anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The breaths should definitely be in the dialogue stem but also available in helper tracks (options track) for the foreign M&E. Most foreign dubs will use their own breaths from the foreign voice actor, but it's good to give them the option. Same with screams and singing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've never mixed on a big stage like 20th Century or WB,

But in my humble opinion, it really depends on if you're going to need it for foreign overdubs.

If overdubbing, it might be a good idea to place it in with the FX so it's there for the foreign dubbing team who then don't have to re-create it.

If doing an English only mix, I would place it on the dia stem.

To me, it makes more sense to put it on the dia, but I also like to take into account those later on the chain.

Cheers,

Comment: Not doing any foreign dubbing for this short, I am going to be the mixer on it but there may be a possibility of someone else also working on it.  I think ill keep it in the dx stem.

Answer (score 0):

to separate dialogue stem track.